# Stored procedure results from a different environment to my development machine as a dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dataset

I have this utility method below, which takes a DataSet and returns an instance of an `XmlDocument`.

I'm trying to execute a complex stored procedure in a different environment, which returns several data tables. I want to somehow feed that DataSet to this method below, to convert it into an `XmlDocument` for further analysis.

The reason for this is, my development machine cannot reach the SQL Server where I want this stored procedure to be executed. But I can manually execute the stored procedure in that environment.

How to do this? None of the examples I found deal with DataSets in such a context.

```
public static XmlDocument Convert(DataSet ds)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.LoadXml(ds.GetXml());
    return xmlDocument;
}
```

Update - This is a strongly typed dataset with an XSD file that defines its schema.

Comment: If you can't reach the SQL Server how will you get the DataSet to convert it to XML? If you have access to machine(s) in that other environment perhaps you could deploy a web service of some kind that returns the required data in XML or JSON format?

Comment: Fix the connection problem to server.  I you can get to server with SQL Server Management Studio you can also connect with code.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Thank you; the idea is to debug the data from QA environment in my local VM, which is not allowed to connect directly to the QA environment. It is too difficult to replicate that scenario in my local environment.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to extract the dataset in XML as a file which can be transferred across different environments using [WriteXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.writexml?view=netframework-4.8.1).

```
public static void WriteToFile(DataSet ds, string xmlFile)
{
    ds.WriteXml(xmlFile, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
}
```

Get back the dataset by reading the XML in your dev environment using [ReadXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.readxml?view=netframework-4.8.1).

```
public static DataSet ReadFromFile(string xmlFile)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    return ds.ReadXml(xmlFile, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
}
```

Comment: How to extract the dataset in XML?

Comment: You can get back the dataset by reading the XML using ReadXml.